# select dropdown option selected by jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I need to select option while  load some content by ajax. here is the code..

```
<select id="select" name="select" onchange="onClick(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="1"  >Yes</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
```

```js
function onClick(value) {
    var p = document.getElementById('select'); 
    if(p.value != value) {
            $('select>option:eq(1)').prop('selected',true)); /*this portion doesn't work */  
    } 
    setTimeout("onClick(1)",5000); /* value 1 for display yes which will display by ajax load file add.php but i can't select yes which already set by ajx url and load content */ 
    } 
    $.ajax({
        url:'add.php',
        type:'GET', 
        data : {id : value}, 
        success : function(response){
            $('div#content').html(response);
        } 
    });  
}});}
```

Comment: The first job you have is to fix the numerous syntax errors in your javascript. The next would be to describe what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Do you mean after the ajax response you will get data to analyse and change the select after that?

Comment: this line  $('select>option:eq(1)').prop('selected',true)); doesn't work..i need to select 'yes' in dropdown box..while ajax load by setTimeout();

Comment: It doesn't work because your preceding `if` statement is incorrect. `if() {p.value != value) {` looks a bit...wrong doesn't it?

Comment: i just misplace while type this code... i need selected 'Yes' at option while ajax load by setTimeout(), setTimeout() make run this function again..at this time my content will be change but select option remains same..i just need to change select option too..thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can update you code like this:
Html:

```
<select id="select" name="select">
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
</select>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#select').on('change', function(){
     //Here $(this) is the "select" select;
     if($(this).val() !== '1'){
        $(this).val('1');   //You can set val to select the option which you want.
     }
     .....
  });
});
```

By the way, I still can't follow the rest part of your code. Hope this can make sense for you.